# Selling apple stock (1st In 1st Out)

Tags: c

Can anybody help me with my code , i have a problem when im selling my apples,
it subtract all of my stocks & sometimes the number goes negative when my input exceeds the stocks

```
int main(void){

int choice = 0;
int days = 1, i, buyApple;
int stocks[99] = {0};

for (;;){

    clrscr();
    printf("Day %d\n", days);

    printf("1. harvest\n");
    printf("2. View Stocks\n");
    printf("3. Sell\n");
    printf("\nchoice: ");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

    if (choice == 1){

        clrscr();
        printf("Input No. of Apple harvested: ");
        scanf("%d", &stocks[days]);
        days++;
    }
    if (choice == 2){

        clrscr();
        printf("Day    Stocks\n");

        for (i = 1; i < days; i++){

            printf("%2d     %4d\n", i, stocks[i]);      
    }
     getch();

    }
    if(choice == 3){

        printf("Input No. of Appple to be sold: ");
        scanf("%d", &buyApple);

        for (i = 0; i < buyApple; i++){
          stocks[i] = stocks[i] - buyApple;

    }
    if(stocks[i] > buyApple)

        printf("Out of Stocks!");

        getch();    
    }

}
}
```

Expecting Output:

for example my stocks is this

```
  Day    Stocks
     1      100
     2       50
     3       50
     4      180
     5      200
```

if i input No. apples to be sold is 200

my stocks will become like this

```
Day    Stocks
  1        0
  2        0
  3        0
  4      180
  5      200
```

1st in 1st out

and when my Input exceeds the stocks it will say `"Out of Stocks !"` and it will not continue reduce my stocks

Comment: Hint: your logic for the case `choice == 3` is totally wrong.

Comment: why ? is my loop is wrong

Comment: Take a piece of paper and a pencil and simulate what is going on, then you will understand. Another hint: look at `for (i = 0; i < buyApple; i++)`: why do you use `buyApple` here?

Comment: @Star_iCe I updated the code to be in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in third choice as in question comments ,the correct code should be like this (it's c#) :

```
if (choice == 3)
{

    printf("Input No. of Appple to be sold: ");
    scanf("%d", &buyApple);


    for (i = 1; i < sizeof(stocks); i++) //Looping on all stocks you have
    {
        if (buyApple <= stocks[i]) //if amount of apple less than stock apples ,then remove them from stock
        {
            stocks[i] = stocks[i] - buyApple;
            buyApple = 0;
            break;

        }
        else //if amount of apple is bigger than stock apples
        {
            if ((sizeof(stocks) - 1) == i){ //if it's the Last stock,then there is no apples in stock
                printf("Out of Stocks!");
            }
            else //take amount of apples from current stock 
            {
                buyApple = buyApple - stocks[i];
                stocks[i] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: i don't understand

Comment: I updated the comments in code , please review it and notify if you still not understand, the root cause is you need to loop on your stocks and check their number of apples and compare it to the amount of apples you want to sell.

Comment: for (i = 1; i < stocks.Length; i++) the length mean the size of stocks?

Comment: This code is serve first in first out, you could specify more on this case

Comment: @Midineo the question was about C, so you should answer in C.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm sorry i didn't notice your comment until now , I will rechange the code to C